# remove invalid character from a String in XML style

Tags: java, xml

I'm create a web service which receive string and convert it to XML. The XML creation is done through java dom4j. The string's format is like:

```
<form01><Textbox1 id="Textbox1" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1</Textbox2></form01>
```

To avoid XML invalid character I think I can use a StringReader to read string and remove &,but I wonder how to remove < and >?For example if the input string is

```
<form01><Textbox1 id="Textbox1" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site<1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1</Textbox2></form01>
```

how to remove the '<' in "Site<1" while keep others like ?
Any suggestion?Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the XML APIs will take care when setting the text in an XML DOM, or retrieving it later.

Some characters will be converted to an XML entity: `< > " ' &`.

There are also [some Characters not allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML) in some XML versions, like `\u0000`.

[apache.commons.lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) has a `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML` if you need to do the conversion yourself as pure text.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following RegExp:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str = "<form01><Textbox1 id=\"Textbox1\" dataType=\"java.lang.String\" perDataProId=\"\">Site<1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id=\"Textbox2\" dataType=\"java.lang.String\" perDataProId=\"\">Site1>a</Textbox2><Textbox3 id=\"Textbox2\" dataType=\"java.lang.String\" perDataProId=\"\">Site1&</Textbox3></form01>";
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(>[^<>]*)<([^<>]*<\\/)", "$1&lt;$2"));
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(>[^<>]*)>([^<>]*<\\/)", "$1&gt;$2"));
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(>[^<>]*)\\&([^<>]*<\\/)", "$1&amp;$2"));
  }
```

Results:

```
<form01><Textbox1 id="Textbox1" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site&lt;1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1>a</Textbox2><Textbox3 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1&</Textbox3></form01>
<form01><Textbox1 id="Textbox1" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site<1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1&gt;a</Textbox2><Textbox3 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1&</Textbox3></form01>
<form01><Textbox1 id="Textbox1" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site<1</Textbox1><Textbox2 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1>a</Textbox2><Textbox3 id="Textbox2" dataType="java.lang.String" perDataProId="">Site1&amp;</Textbox3></form01>
```

In any case, I would consider using [Guava HtmlEscapers](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/html/HtmlEscapers.html). The RegExp for this case are a fragile overhead.